# Correlated Subquery with Join

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: alert, user_to_alert, and user_device.  The device table holds a list of tokens and and includes a user_id field.

The user_to_alert table holds records of when a user reads an alert.  If a record doesn't exist for the appropriate alert_id/user_id combo, it means the user hasn't read the alert.  There is also an alert_read column that can be zero (if the user marks the alert as unread after reading it).

I have a query that loads a list of device tokens and I need to expand this to include the number of unread alerts. This is the query I've come up with

```
SELECT d.*, (
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `alert` AS a 
LEFT JOIN `user_to_alert` AS uta ON 
( uta.`alert_id` = a.`alert_id` AND uta.`user_id` = d.`user_id` ) 
WHERE uta.`alert_read` = 0 OR uta.`alert_read` IS NULL) AS user_badge_number 
FROM `user_device` AS d  
WHERE d.`device_type` = 'iOS' AND d.`device_active` = 1 
GROUP BY d.`device_token`
```

This query gives me error `#1054 - Unknown column 'd.user_id' in 'on clause'`

I've setup an SQLFiddle with the schema and query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee653/2

If I run my sub-query separately and substitute d.user_id for a valid user_id, I get the expected results (i.e. 3 for user_id 10).  I assume this means the problem is where I'm referencing the column d.user_id.  I guess MySQL is trying to perform the subquery first so d.user_id isn't a valid column yet?  That's just a guess though.

I've tried moving the `uta.user_id = d.user_id` part of my ON clause to the WHERE clause but that just gives all rows a 0 for the user_badge_number column.

I'm having trouble finding anything via Google that relates to this issue.  Everything I find about correlated subqueries seems to be using them in ON or WHERE clauses instead of using them to retrieve extra data.

This is being run via a PHP script, so I know that I could run the sub query by itself within the result loop of the PHP script.  Obviously, I'd rather figure out how to do it with one query as that would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, its not hard to count the number of alerts that were read. You can subtract that from total alerts to get the number unread:

```
SELECT d.*, 
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `alert` ) - 
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user_to_alert` 
        WHERE `user_id` = d.`user_id` AND `alert_read` = 1 )
FROM `user_device` AS d 
WHERE d.`device_active` AND d.`device_type` = 'iOS';
```

But note there is an issue with the design, which is that if a device or user is added 6 months from now, all the alerts from the past will show up as unread on that new device. There are similar problems if a device gets reassigned to a new user, or an existing user switches devices (depending on whether you are counting unread alerts *per user* or *per device*).

To get around this you could restrict the query to a particular date range 9since the user or device was added, though in the case of a device being reassigned its not clear what date to use.)  I think a simpler answer is to insert rows into `user_to_alert` as each alert is created. This would have several advantages:

- easy to count the number of unread rows for a user or device
- new devices/users don't inherit old alerts
- lets you add a new feature: alerts that are directed to only some users/devices

Comment: I am tracking alert reads based on the user, not the device.  If a user has more than one device, their unread count will be identical for all devices. You do have a good point about users created after alerts are sent out. I could avoid this issue by restricting the total count to only alerts sent after the user's account was created. I'm going to remove my answer and accept yours as it is a bit better with the subtraction within the query itself.

Comment: Good point about using the date range to fix the issue I brought up. I have edited my answer to include that suggestion.

Comment: FWIW your deleted answer was what gave me the idea to do the subtraction. My first draft used a CROSS JOIN to count the number of unread; the subtraction was much simpler.

Comment: I figured my answer helped a bit but since you put in the time to expand on it, I figured it would be better to just keep yours and use it as the accepted answer :)  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's a scope problem in the correlated subquery, try to use the table name

```
SELECT d.*, (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `alert` AS a 
    LEFT JOIN `user_to_alert` AS uta ON 
    ( uta.`alert_id` = a.`alert_id`) 
    WHERE  uta.`user_id` = d.`user_id`  AND 
            (uta.`alert_read` = 0 OR uta.`alert_read` IS NULL)) 
            AS user_badge_number 
FROM `user_device` AS d
WHERE d.`device_type` = 'iOS' AND d.`device_active` = 1 
GROUP BY d.`device_token`
```

Comment: Changing the query as you've suggested does fix the error but it's not giving me the right value for user_badge_number.  I've adjust the SQLFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee653/19) and it's giving me 3 for both results.  It should be giving me 3 for user #10 and 7 for user #11.

Comment: @Kid, that doesn't seem to be giving the right results either but I can't figure out why.  When I read it, it seems like it should work but it seems to be giving the read count instead of the unread count.